# Automatic Summarization : Extraction Based

Tags: python, nlp, summarization

What is the algorithm of extraction based automatic summarization ? googled alot, couldnt find anything related to it . I want to implement the algo on python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one single algorithm for extraction based summarization. There are several different algorithms to choose from. You should choose one that fits your specific needs.

There are two approaches to extraction based summarization:

- Supervised learning - you give the program lots of examples of documents together with their keywords. The program learns what constitutes a keyword. Then you give it a new document, this time without any keywords, and the program extracts the keywords of this document based on what it learned during the training phase. There is a huge number of supervised learning techniques. To name a few, there are neural networks, decision trees, random forests and support vector machines.
- Unsupervised learning - you simly give the program a document and it creates a list of keywords without relying on any past experience. A popular unsupervised algorithm for extraction based summarization is TextRank.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you should learn more about how to find papers and research. It is absolutely impossible if you haven't found anything by google. In any case, some of the extraction based text summarziation are:

1. Easy to implement methods based on word frequency
2. Bayesian methods
3. Graph based methods eg TextRank/LexRank is a good start.
4. Clustering
5. Fuzzy Systems for summarization
6. Neural Network based system
7. I have seen methods based on optimization algorithms
   I suggest googling these methods and see what you get. There are a lot of variations for these and I can't really tell what method is the best. Remember to find proper preprocessing tools as well.
   Good luck.